# Firebae with mediaplayer.setDataSource() gives an err

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to get url from firebase and give it to mediaplayer.setDataSource but I get an err says :- `

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:991)
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:944)
                      at mks.master.musest.home$onCreateView$16$1$1.onDataChange(home.kt:425)
                      at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
                      at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                      at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
`
```

here is my code :-

```
`var mediaplayer:MediaPlayeria
                mediaplayer=MediaPlayer()
                firebase= Firebase(link+"song2song")
                firebase.addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: FirebaseError?) {
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                        mediaplayer.setDataSource(p0.getValue(String()::class.java))
                        mediaplayer.prepareAsync()

                    }

                })`
```

and the main err is in this part `mediaplayer.setDataSource(p0.getValue(String()::class.java))`

Comment: What's the value of `p0.getValue(String()::class.java)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `reset()` before calling `setDataSource()`.

Look at the following [state diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#state-diagram) in Android reference, it gives you a clear vision of the different states of `MediaPlayer`

Also [This table](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#Valid_and_Invalid_States) shows that `setDataSource()` can be executed from Idle state only.